# How to setup a basic line chart in React / Next.js with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, chart.js

Standard setup I has:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
        "next": "12.2.3",
        "react-chartjs-2": "^4.3.1",
    },
```

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { Line, Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2'
import { CategoryScale } from 'chart.js'

export default function Home() {
    const router = useRouter()
    ChartJS.register(CategoryScale)

    const data = {
        labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'First dataset',
                data: [33, 53, 85, 41, 44, 65],
                fill: true,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,0.2)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
            },
            {
                label: 'Second dataset',
                data: [33, 25, 35, 51, 54, 76],
                fill: false,
                borderColor: '#742774',
            },
        ],
    }

    return (
        <Line data={data} />
    )
}
```

But raise error:

> Error: "category" is not a registered scale.

So I found this: https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/faq/registered-scale/

Added those line, but hey, where `ChartJS` comes from, or what should I write instead of it?

```js
import { CategoryScale } from "chart.js";

ChartJS.register(CategoryScale);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not registering the category scale, so you will need to import the chart from chartjs itself and register the category scale on there.

```js
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { CategoryScale, Chart } from 'chart.js';

Chart.register(CategoryScale);
```

**Edit**
Putted in a PR that clarifies this, link shows how to resolve the error correctly now